# What is the mathematical "set" function can be used to represent the uniqueness of a set?

Tags: functions, multisets

What is the mathematical set function that can satisfy the following

if X = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Y = (1, 3, 4, 2, 5), Z = (1, 1, 3, 2, 5);

Then

F(X) = F(Y) ≠ F(Z)

what function "F" can be used to check that a specific known set is equal to another set regardless of the order of its values.

I hope I could explain it enough

As an example, I thought of the "Sum" function for the range from 1 to 4 but:

Sum(1,2,3,4) will be equal to Sum(2,2,3,3)

Thanks

Comment: Uniqueness and equality to another set are different qualities and would relate to different functions.

Comment: You could use $F(X)=X$. If you want $F(X)=F(Y)$ if and only if $X=Y$, for all sets $X$ and $Y$, I think it's going to have to be something silly like that.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Basically, I need to calculate a measure to the sets to deduce that X = Y and that what i need

Comment: You need to give more details about the kind of values you can have in your tuples. Are they all integers?

Comment: @AliceRyhl  yes they are all integers

Comment: If you think $X\neq Y$ in your question then you are using the wrong notation for $X$ and $Y$. But you have an answer below that shows what I think you meant to write, and it seems you agree.

Comment: Can I ask what application this is for? If it's purely theoretical, there are some neat ways of encoding sets as numbers but if it's practical or in a programming language, you can usually just compare tuples directly.

Comment: @DavidK   what I meant is X and Y have the same elements regardless of the order and that what I am looking for a function to deduce it

Comment: I see you have fixed the notation. That makes the question much clearer.

Comment: One thing that is not clear (yet) from the question: should we see $F(1,1,2) = F(1,2)$ or $F(1,1,2)\neq F(1,2)$? That is, we know you want the order of numbers to not make a difference (so $F(1,2)=F(2,1)$), but does the _multiplicity_ of numbers make a difference (that is, does it matter whether $1$ occurs twice or just once)? If multilplicity makes a difference you have a multiset, otherwise you have a set. Obviously the algorithms to distinguish multisets are different from algorithms to distinguish sets.

Comment: @DavidK  yes the multiplicity makes a difference, please check this answer
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3556392/753336
It is the solution

Comment: Yes, now that you have said multiplicity matters, I agree that is a correct answer. (it is terribly impractical, but correct.) I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at here are not sets but (presumably finite) sequences, or tuples. Sets don't have repeated elements, and the elements in a set are not in any particular order. To write a tuple we use parentheses instead of curly braces, so your examples would be $(1,2,3,4,5)$, $(1,1,3,2,5)$, etc.

You can assign an integer to any tuple of positive integers that uniquely determines the tuple. Namely, let $p_1,p_2,\ldots$ be the primes in order and let $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ be the tuple, and define 
$$F(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_n^{a_n}$$
Then two tuples will be equal if and only if the associated integers are equal, by unique factorization of integers.

Edit: I noticed that in your post you said you want to ignore the order of the elements. In that case you could do instead
$$F(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=p_{a_1}p_{a_2}\cdots p_{a_n}$$

Comment: This is a good way of doing it but I believe it misses the stipulation of "regardless of order". We would have the two tuples $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,3,2)$ mapped to $2^13^25^3=2250\ne 1350=2^13^35^2$. But it is trivial to sort the tuples beforehand.

Comment: I haven't the welfare to sort them first, and this what makes me search for a function that can do the job for me

Comment: @user I found an alternative solution. See the post.

Comment: @MattSamuel     it won't lead to the result because 4*5 will gave the same result of 2*10 and they are different p values

Comment: @user $10$ would never occur as an individual factor. It would be $2\cdot 2\cdot 5$, which has the three elements $1,1,3$.

Comment: @user12552926 Each new element, $a_n$, added to the tuple will either be encoded in a new prime, $p_{a_n}$, if it hasn't appeared before, or will be encoded in the power of an earlier prime, $p_{a_k}^{2}$, where $a_k$ was a previous element equal to $a_n$. The method implicitly bunches up multiple occurrences of elements. Very nice method, Matt.

Comment: @MattSamuel         It is excellent, a genius solution
 I haven't read it well, p should be a prime

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare two sets at once, the binary function that indicates whether two arguments are equal is known as the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) and is defined simply as $\delta_{ij}=\begin{cases}1,&i=j\\0,&\text{else}\end{cases}$. It is usually defined for integers but you could extend its definition to sets, e.g., $\delta(X,Y)=\begin{cases}1,&X=Y\\0,&\text{else}\end{cases}$. This is effectively just an algebraic way of saying whether the sets are equal. Equality of sets is defined regardless of the order of their elements so that isn't a problem.

Alternatively, if you want to compare sets by individually assigning each of them a value as you suggested in the question, you could do something along the lines of encoding the sets sorted elements into a number. But I don't think there is any benefit to this.

Efficient ways of encoding the elements will depend on whether the elements are integers or reals, whether the set is finite, etc. For your finite sets of integers, you could assign the integers a prime, $p_i$, and encode each integer's digits on the prime indexed digits of the function's value. Primes are useful since no two elements digits will coincide. So you would have $f(X)=f(\left\{1,2,3,4,5\right\})=50004030210$ since we assign $1\mapsto 2$, $2\mapsto3$, $3\mapsto 5$, etc and we ignore the value of the unit decimal by setting it to $0$. We could then extract the elements, e.g., $5$ by looking at the decimals of $50004030210$ that are multiples of $11$. We would then have $f(Y)=f(\left\{1,3,4,2,5\right\})=f(\left\{1,2,3,4,5\right\})=50004030210$ after sorting. The values are equal but this doesn't tell us much since we had to sort the argument sets anyway, and I think we would inevitably have to if we wanted to compare them. $Z$ isn't a true set; it's a multiset. In a true set, elements can appear at most once. Regardless, its two $1$'s can be encoded just like any other number. So, you would have $f(Z)=50003020110$, which is not equal.

If you had real number elements, or infinite elements, you could adapt your procedure to encoding sets in real number values, where the prime indexed decimal expansion of the number encodes each element.

Comment: Thank you but the problem with me is that I want to avoid sorting and other kinds of programming, I just need a direct way of calculating the output to compare different sets

Comment: @user12552926 I believe you will inevitably need to sort the tuples since otherwise they aren't equal.

Comment: @user12552926 Sorting is a perfectly well-defined mathematical function on a sequence of integers. It only becomes "programming" when you want to do it on a computer. In fact I view the mapping of the multiset into a single number as much closer to a "kind of programming" than merely sorting the numbers would be, because its essentially an _encoding_ of the multiset, and encoding data is what computers do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question properly, but it seems you are searching for the function $F:X^n\to \mathcal{P}(X)$ (where $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is the set of subsets of $X$)
given by
$$(x_1,\dots,x_n)  \mapsto  \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}. $$

Indeed it will detect only the set of elements in your tuple, regardless of order or repetitions, and will satisfy the example in your question.